# How to stream data from python to javascript

Tags: javascript, python, stream

I am looking for a way to stream data from python script to a javascript within a html file.

My data is stored in a large `csv` file which looks like:

```
x1,x2,y1,y2
0.5,0.54,0.04,0.55
0.12,0.88,1.02,0.005
...
...
```

The python script must pre-process this data before sending it to javascript:

```py
import csv

def send_data(filename):
    with open(filename, "rb") as csvfile:
        datareader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        for row in datareader:
            preprocessed = Do_something(row)
            yield preprocessed
```

The javascript should process the received data from the python script above.

Comment: JavaScript "within a HTML file" can't access a file on a filesystem unless a user explicitly selects the file through a file input.

Comment: Do you have any permission problem? Why don't you read the CSV file from JS instead?

Answer (score 1):

Without *knowing* more about your *exact* requirements you could do something like this using [circuits](https://github.com/circuits/circuits):

**Code:** (*untested*)

```
import csv

from circuits.web import Server, Controller

def Do_something(row):
    return row

class Root(Controller):

    def send_data(self, filename):
        self.response.stream = True

        with open(filename, "rb") as csvfile:
            datareader = csv.reader(csvfile)
            for row in datareader:
                preprocessed = Do_something(row)
                yield preprocessed


app = Server(("0.0.0.0", 8000))
Root().register(app)
app.run()
```

Then requests to http://localhost:8000/send_data/filename would result in a stream resolve of the entire csv file. This also *assumes* you actually want to serve up the csv file as a web response to some web application.